# Java FileReader put ((char) i), k++) in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, filereader

I am trying to read the contents of a file and count how often each letter appears. This is my situation:

```
public static void readFile() throws Exception {

    Map<Character, Integer> lcount = new HashMap<>();

    for (Character letter = 'A'; letter <= 'Z'; letter++) {
        lcount.put(letter, 0);
    }

    try {
        FileReader reader = new FileReader("file.txt");
        for (int i = 1; i != -1; i = reader.read()) {
            int k = lcount.get((char) i);
            lcount.put((char) i) ,k++);
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("The file does not exist.");
    }
}
```

I cannot use ((char) i, k++) to increase the letter count in my HashMap.

The exception says: **put (Character, Integer) in Map cannot be applied to (char)**

How can I read the value of type Character at location i and use it as a key to put a value to it in my HashMap?

Thanks in advance.

> EDIT: Thanks to @Ferrybig. I just missed a "(". I thought it was about
>   the variable type.

Comment: what if `reader.read()` yields letter out of range 'A' - 'Z' ?

Comment: @Arvind I'm not there yet. Its for school, so I'll take one step after the other.

Comment: You made a small typo: `lcount.put((char) i) ,k++);`, it should be `lcount.put(((char) i) ,k++);` or `lcount.put((char) i ,k++);`

Comment: note that `char != Character`

Comment: @Ferrybig Oh thanks! That's it. Stupid me.

Comment: Your `for` loop is not right. It starts by processing the character 1 which is not part of the file.

Comment: why use a `Map` and not an array? `int[] counts = new int['Z' - 'A' + 1]; ...  char ch = <uppercase letter>; counts[ch - 'A'] += 1;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `k + 1`:

```
for (int i = 1; i != -1; i = reader.read()) {
    int k = lcount.get((char) i);
    lcount.put((char) i, k + 1);
}
```

`k++` returns the original value of `k` (prior to the increment).

Or:

```
for (int i = 1; i != -1; i = reader.read()) {
    lcount.put((char) i, lcount.get((char) i) + 1);
}
```

Comment: I cannot apply Character from the HashMap to char. (char) i) is the problematic part since it's of the wrong type.

Comment: @FFRA I just noticed you had an extra `)` after `(char) i`.

Answer (score 0):

without method get():

```
for (int i = 1; i != -1; i = reader.read()) {
    lcount.compute((char) i, (x, i) -> i + 1);
}
```